# Databinding: Accessing fields in included layout - layout is cast to view

Tags: android, android-databinding

I'm using databinding in my project and it is working as expected.
Now I'd like to use the `<include>` tag and access fields in the included layout and I can't get it to work.

I tried a code snippet that I've found multiple times on the web which is the following:

hello_world.xml

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/hello"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <include
                android:id="@+id/included"
                layout="@layout/included_layout"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

included_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/world"/>
</layout>
```

```
HelloWorldBinding binding =
    HelloWorldBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
binding.hello.setText("Hello");
binding.included.world.setText("World");
```

And this code doesn't work.
When I look in android studio, `binding.included` is a View and therefore there is no way to access the fields.

`binding.hello.setText("Hello");` Works properly so databinding is working at least on some level.

How can I access the fields in the included layout?

Comment: clean your code and restart android studio

Comment: I tried that @unzila but it still doesn't work.
I have Canary 3.6 5. Could potentially be an issue with my setup.

Comment: you invalidate and restart android studio?

Comment: @ErikSillén could you please try my answer

Comment: @unzila yes I've tried that - didn't work.

Comment: @ManojPerumarath tried - didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set Android DataBinding in nested layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38464478/how-to-set-android-databinding-in-nested-layouts)

Comment: close-vote retracted, because it's only related, but not an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your included layout (included_layout.xml) inside a ViewGroup. This would fix the issue. `included_layout.xml` should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/world"/>

 </RelativeLayout>

</layout>
```

Therefore, when you want to setText your TextView, you can do something like this:

```
binding.included.world.setText("World");
```

### Summary

Every time you use the `include` tag, the `include` tag serves as a place holder for the outermost layout in your included view (which should be a ViewGroup). Therefore, when using the `include` tag, the outermost view in your included layout must always be a ViewGroup.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that but it didn't solve the problem :/

Comment: Is there a layout_width and layout_height in the `layout` element of your `included_layout`? If yes, remove it just like in my code above.

Comment: I have the code from my question and used your code like you wrote it. Still doesn't work. I'm suspecting that something is wrong with my setup.

Comment: ...must always be a ViewGroup, unless it's a `<merge>` tag. Can't you also remove the layout tag in the included layout?

Comment: @AjahnCharles I don't think the layout tag is the cause of OP's problem (everything looks okay) but I agree that it's worth trying. Also, I specified that the outermost view must be a viewgroup **if the `include` tag is being used**. I guess I didn't express myself well. I've edited my answer to that effect. Thanks!

Comment: I was just curious how binding works for the edge case of `<merge>`; "To avoid including such a redundant view group, you can instead use the <merge> element as the root view for the re-usable layout" https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts

Comment: @AjahnCharles Ohh! I see the point now. Sounds like an approach that would work. I think you should add this as an answer.

Comment: @AjahnCharles Let me know if/when you do.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure not to set `id` on the `include` and on the included layout (both must only have a single `id`). That included layout might likely require a `<data />` node, which may be empty (when not passing variables from the parent layout, as the one answer which I've linked above does).

Alike this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hello"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <include
            layout="@layout/included_layout"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

And this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/world"/>

</layout>
```

Comment: How do you access `world.setText` then?

Answer (score -2):

Remove that layout tag

included_layout.xml

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/world"/>
```

then try it `binding.included.world.setText("World")`

A closer example

```
class NavigationActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var activityNavigationBinding:ActivityNavigationBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    activityNavigationBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(
        this,
        R.layout.activity_navigation
    )
    activityNavigationBinding.includeLayout.tv_textView.setText("Sample text")
   }
}
```

activity_navigation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
            android:id="@+id/includeLayout"
            layout="@layout/app_bar_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_navigation"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</layout>
```

app_bar_navigation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.NavigationActivity">

  <TextView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/tv_textView"
       />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

After that you need to call like
bindingObject.(id of include layout).(id of the view).setText or anything

Comment: This only works for a trivial example. I expect the real code has more than one child view.

Comment: @AjahnCharles if that's the case, the viewgroup should be the parent, it's a simple commonsense